# Spring Paging with custom paging links

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I pass through pageable to my spring rest controller method the method then returns a page of people and returns paging links like the following:

```
_links": {
    "first": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/people?page=1&size=1000"
    },
    "last": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/people?page=1&size=1000"
    },
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/people?page=1&size=1000"
    }
}
```

Is there code I can call within the page object that is being returned to change these links specifically I would like to change http to https.

Where and how would I do this. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: by default spring boot run on http protocole and to run it on https you have to create a SSL certificat. you already have it ? if not you can take a look here : https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Thank you, but I would really like an understanding about how to get to and modify the actual paging links. Do you know how I can do that through code?

Comment: All right ! so could you put an example of code that help you to return these urls ?